# How do I have my code trigger an event when a file is added to a given folder?

Tags: c#, events, directory

I am trying to have my software run a command line instruction whenever a certain type of file is added to a given folder. 
So far I have the ability for a user to select the folder, and the path is saved to a string. 
I am just wondering if there is some kind of event that could be called when a change is made to that folder? 
(c#)

Comment: search for FileSystemWatcher

Comment: Haha yeah just found it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect when a directory or file changes without constant scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3215619/how-do-i-detect-when-a-directory-or-file-changes-without-constant-scanning)

Answer (score 0):

I think what I was looking for is called 'File System Watcher' and a guide can be found here: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lVormV8cb8